# Listview : different padding for header & content

Tags: android, android-listview

I am working on an extensive codebase and I need to add an header to most of its ListViews.
My trouble is that the header needs to have no padding whereas the existing lists already have a 20dp padding.
It could setup the listview padding to 0dp & rewrite all the listview content layouts but due to the size of the codebase that's not the preferred option so I am looking for a way to do this by code :
have a different padding for the header & the content. Does anyone know a way to do this ?

edit : for clarification : I need that header to be a standard listview one that scrolls with the rest of the listview. An independant header would indeed be a trivial problem.

Comment: You must be having separate layout for ListView Item and Header View. SO remove padding from ListView and move that to item's layout and header's layout.

Comment: Can you please explain this by putting image and in that show what exactly the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the right way to do this efficiently :
set the list padding to 0 when the view is created, for example when its listfragment is initialized :

```
setPadding(0,0,0,0);
```

and in the *Adapter* , set the padding of each element :

```
getViewFor (Item element, int globalPosition, int elementPosition,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
...
convertView.setPadding(getItemPadding());
}
```

That way I can get different paddings for the header & list itself (in my case I wanted 0 padding for the header) at a minimal code & perf cost.

Answer (score 0):

make header into a different view and then

```
   mListView.addHeaderView(R.layout.mHeaderView);
```

Comment: nope, still submitted to the same padding as the rest of the listview

Comment: Then don't add your padding to the listview, but add it to your listview items

Comment: oh and if you need that header to be "sticky" don't add it to the listview, or are you getting several headers for one listview?

Answer (score -1):

@Artoo is right the best thing you could do is have a textview above your listView and you can have any padding added to it as its not associated with your ListView.

Below is my snippet.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:text="I am Header"/>
<ListView 
   android:id="@+id/list"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
    >

</ListView>
```

and here is my output. (I know its looks bizarre) but it works. :)
[image]

Do let me know if you need further help. Happy coding. :)

Comment: I don't need a sticky header, that would indeed be very easy to do :).

Comment: Could you please add a snippet of your code, that will help to understand the issue better? If I understood the situation correctly your list items have a padding of 20dp and you don't want the header to have this. If this is the scenario, you should add the padding to your layout you are inflating within the list. As your header will be a separate view, it will not have any effect of the padding. Lemme know if I am missing on anything.

Comment: As explained in the question, I am working on an extensive codebase, so while adding padding to each kind of listview item is indeed the more direct solution, in this case it means rewriting many complex layouts so I am looking for another way.

Comment: Try adding the padding (it rhymes :)) to the outer most layout of your ListView items, so if your having 10different layout you will only have to set them once in the xml or please share your xml and may be screens as well to show what your are getting at the moment and what to desire to achieve.